# Convert Days to Integer in Julia

Tags: julia

I have a duration

```
Day(42)
```

How can I convert it to an `Int64`?

I have one solution, but is there other smart ways to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Dates` package contains the `value` function for this.

```
Day(42) |> Dates.value
```